# Default Gateway is the server not the router

Tags: router

Default gateway of my hostel in college is not the router. Infact, its the server of my college which is 10.x.x.x. So is someone wants to connect to the router to change its setting how would someone do that if he/she doesnt know the address of the router?
Can anyone explain this as I am not able to grasp the concept of Default Gateway.

Comment: Questions related to non-professional networking are not allowed on Network Engineering.

Comment: Questions about residential networking and/or consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic here. You should try to ask this question on [su].

Answer (score 1):

I will answer the part of the question that doesn't violate the posting guidelines; "What is a default gateway?"

A default gateway in networking is the device that "knows" where to forward traffic to. When your PC makes a request, that request is sent to the default gateway if the request is not bound for the local subnet; that default gateway then "knows" either by being programmed or by some routing protocol where to send your request.

The server, or default gateway in your case is most likely a proxy to prevent or log your access of certain web based resources.

Answer (score -2):

A default gateway is a device connected to the LAN.

When a device (PC, Tablet,etc.) needs to connect to an address outside the LAN, then sends the packets to the Default Gateway.

The Default Gateway is connected to other networks, so it is able to forward the packets outside.

In your case as a Default Gateway is a proxy server that "maybe" is filtering protocols (bittorrent, streaming) or destinations (adult content, gambling,etc.) before sending the packets to the real Default Gateway.